# No SelectedItem if ListView created using template

Tags: wpf, templates, listview, selection

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"....
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="lvTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <ListView Width="200" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name"
                                  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"  />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lview" Template="{StaticResource lvTemplate }" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding collection}".../>

        <ListView x:Name="lview2" ItemsSource="{Binding collection2}"...>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"  />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

so, two ListViews, the only difference between them is that the first is created using a template.

If I add elements to collections, new rows appear in both lists, and all is looking fine. But when I select a line in the first ListView (lview), no item is being selected (only visually it is looking selected, in code behind SelectedIndex == -1, SelectedItem == null). One more strange thing, the View property of this ListView is null.
What is here wrong?

Thank you in anvance!

Comment: Why do you build template of `ListView` with another `ListView` where you change the `View`? Why not simply change the `View` of the main `ListView`? These 2 grids are independent hence no selection or view is transferred between them

Comment: I am showing here a simplified code. In a real application there are about ten TabItems, each has a ListView with the same 8 Columns. I simply do not want to let my XAML be several meters long, and if I later have to change something (Column name for instance), I want to have it once only. I have choose maybe not the most elegant way to do it. My purpose is to define all these columns somewere (I have choosed a Template), and then refer it in my ListViews.

Comment: Ok, I ask my question another way: how can I define a GridView (or column definitions) only once, and then reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to share the view between more then `ListView` you can create `GridView` resoucre with [`x:Shared="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx):

```
<GridView x:Key="gridView" x:Shared="False">
   <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"  />
</GridView>
```

and then you can use it, like below, in more then one `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="lview" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" View="{StaticResource gridView}"/>
<ListView x:Name="lview2" ItemsSource="{Binding collection2}" View="{StaticResource gridView}"/>
```

Comment: dkozl, thank you once again! It is just what I was looking for!